# Do I need more then one frame

Tags: ros, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I want to display 15 kites object in rviz. e.g. which is being published on a topic /mytopic. Now If I want to visualise all the cars in rviz with tf, do I have to create a different frame for all my kites and then transfrom from existing frame to the subsequent frame of every kite:

Forexample the following is being published:

```
    id: 0
    x: 5.2867903969
    y: 1.16666697467
  - 
    id: 10
    x: 4.07336703983
    y: 1.47035641195
  - 
    id: 13
    x: 1.05589985089
    y: 0.652519672117
  - 
    id: 18
    x: 2.9798815499
    y: 0.683754740765
  - 
    id: 19
    x: 4.25167338379
    y: 0.621103239893
  - 
    id: 21
    x: 1.07946245091
    y: 0.304702623678
  - 
    id: 27
    x: 5.09639028515
    y: 0.337052136863
  - 
    id: 31
    x: 4.05408506722
    y: 1.21188367731
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71860/do-i-need-more-then-one-frame/) by [Bodgan Mircu](https://answers.ros.org/users/5830/bodgan-mircu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-08-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Simple answer: Yes.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2013-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In TF you would need to add more than 1 frame in order to visualize it in rviz. However I would recommned you to use Marker Arrays for your kites. As you already have the data published over a topic and it is different for every kite so you can use this data and markers arrays to display it. Follow the Markers tutorial on ros wiki, its a very good tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [Asfandyar Ashraf Malik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5044/asfandyar-ashraf-malik/) with karma: 729 on 2013-08-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1